# Is it safe to write an angular app for an admin portal?

Tags: angularjs

Precondition: the server side routes for ajax data calls are all middlewared with authentication.

because client side everything can be altered, ***How can I stop the user from seeing the admin dashboard***, because the routes are secure but the page loading is not and then they would see what the admin dashboard looks like.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want the client to see it, don't send it to the client. That's the only way to be sure.

Comment: the routes that the angular app calls are secure

Comment: I just feel that all angular apps have to be embedded inside another logical serverside framework if thats the case

Comment: will get a lot more out of google on this topic than here since answering is lengthy. And there is lots written on it , as well as modules you can use

Comment: Okay ill check it out. Am I right in saying that writing an angular app with no server side wrapper is just a silly idea unless you dont require someone to be logged in to view a particular interface.

Comment: If you can break your admin into a new angular app (separate page), you can secure everything more effectively.

Comment: for simplicity - why not to have separate app (using Angular and the same APIs) which will be behind simple non-angular authentication page?